# Throwing Error in javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Hi I'm using Javascript for loop to generate a  string on looping C# list but I'm getting Error

```
Error   4   The name 'eventList' does not exist in the current context
```

My complete code is here

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             dataType: 'json',
             contentType: 'application/json',
             url: 'ProjectedYieldCalender.aspx/GetData',
             data: '{}',
             success:
                function (data) {

                    var eventList = data.d;

                    alert(eventList.length);
                   // eventList = demo(eventList);
                    initCalendar(eventList);
                }

         });

     });
function initCalendar(eventList) {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        //defaultDate: '2014-08-12',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [

     <% for (var i = 0; i < eventList.count ; i++) { %>

         {
             title : eventList[<%=i%>].name,
             start : eventList[<%=i%>].date

         }
         <% }%>
        ]

    });


     }

     </script>
```

Cany any one please let me know where am I doing mistake and please let me know how to use the count of list in for loop . I'm getting proper result if I place some static value in for loop like **'i<5' in stead of  'i < eventList.Count'**

Comment: Are you trying to use C# to iterate through a variable that exists in your JavaScript?

Comment: need to learn to understand what language runs in which environment when you start mixing them

Comment: No here I'm getting C# list as object to javascript and then I'm looping the object

Answer (score 1):

You have to do like this. You are trying to access javascript array in asp.net code so it gives you that error.

```
   function initCalendar(eventList) {
        var events = [];
        for(var i=0;i<eventList.length;i++)
        {
           events.push({ title : eventList[i].name , start: eventList[i].date });
        } 

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            //defaultDate: '2014-08-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: events
            });
         }
```

Comment: The above solution is not working for me. I need to get only length of the object list

Comment: What is problem? I am not getting what you are trying to say " I need to get only length of the object list " ?

Comment: I'm not getting any output if I do as you said but I'm getting output at least for static values if I do the way I implemented for loop. So can you please tell me how to get the length of eventlist in my for loop?

Comment: Error : Name "EventList" does not exists will get solve my solution if your data.d is proper list. Your second issue i<5 instead of i<eventList.Length requires some input from your side that how is your data.d look like and what you exactly want as output